# Unity:How to keep IU out of the screen with Anchors top center?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have an UIimage which needs to fall down with tween animation. So the beginning point should be out of the screen. For Screen adaptation reasons, this image must keep it's anchors on top center, but at the same time, the image it self also needs to dock it's bottom at the top of the screen too(Users should not see any part of this image before the animation begin.).If I simply change it's PosY, it won't adapt to all resolutions.
So how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to tween RectTransform.anchoredPosition. Outside Y value will be `rectTransform.sizeDeltra.y / 2`, and inside will be `-rectTransform.sizeDeltra.y / 2 + offset` from top screen edge. If you need to match screen bottom and Image bottom, it will be `rectTransform.sizeDeltra.y / 2 - Screen.height`; If you need to match screen top and image top, it will be `-rectTransform.sizeDeltra.y / 2`; If you need it to be in the center, it would be `-Screen.height / 2`.